# Queue websocket requests until initialized / process queue

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I have a Angular2 websocket application that needs to complete a handshake on connection before I send any other messages.

My "widget" controller uses a "network" service that is a wrapper for websockets

```
import { $WebSocket } from 'angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket';
```

the "widget's" ngOnit is sending a websocket message before the handshake has completed.

How do I ensure that the service queues up outgoing messages / "wait" for the init/handshake to complete before processing?

- RxJS (controlled observer, Subject)?  *(I'm not yet able to massage RxJS's secrets out of its documentation)*
- promise?
- Something already built into Angular (such as deferring my controller's init until service has initialized)?

I feel like I'm making this harder than it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to make the fact that there is handshake needed first transparent for the rest of the application.

You can store the messages sent by the rest of the application in a [replay subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md), where they will be pilled up for later consumption.

You want to set the buffer size to a value that would keep all the messages but not cause memory problems.

Later when the handshake is completed, you subscribe to the replay subject and you would get all the messages that need to be sent now that the websocket handshake is completed.

For the rest of the application this buffering is transparent: the rest of the app is calling `messageService.send()` that is internally buffering this in a `ReplaySubject`.

The message sender subscribes to the replay subject and get all messages to be sent: it has no indication if the messages are buffered or being sent in real time, that is transparent for the consumer of the buffered messages.

Comment: This looks very promising..   any idea why tsc would throw `error TS2339: Property 'onNext' does not exist on type 'ReplaySubject<any>'`

Comment: bum documentation...  `onNext()`, should be `next()`  https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md